# Does blobstore service retain the file creation date (not upload date)?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, date, blobstore, creation

How can I capture the original file creation date of an image file that's been uploaded to the blobstore?

All similar questions/answers seem to refer to the *upload* date of the image.  I'm interested in the date at which (in this case) the photo was taken.

Btw, my apologies if this is a total newb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers won't send the file creation date when uploading images, so you won't have it on the server side (whether you use AppEngine/Blobstore or not).

For photos though, cameras generally save the date within the file, as EXIF metadata (or IPTC or XMP).  I don't know if there's any API usable in AppEngine that'd allow you to access the EXIF metadata.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  There seem to be a few parties out there who wrote libraries to extract the metadata.  For now it's down on the priorities list, so I'll pick it up again later.  Cheers!